# Create a url from JSON in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am able to output my SQL query to JSON using the `FOR JSON` command in my query. What I need to do is make that JSON data available via a live URL that I can fetch anytime I want a fresh dataset from the SQL Server.

Most of my research shows me how to either A) work with JSON inside SSMS, or B) output JSON from SSMS. What I need is a way to take my JSON output, store it somewhere external to my SQL server with a unique URL that will allow me to use the fetchURL command in my Google Scripts to update data in my Google Sheet from my SQL Server. I already know how to parse JSON data to my spreadsheet, and I already know how to get my SQL data into JSON format. The missing link is creating a URL for the JSON data that is live connected to my SQL Server database that refreshes every time I fetch it. Below is the SQL code that creates the JSON object (it is the Aeries Demo Database for their Student Information System...the query returns all the grades for all students at a high school...this is fictitious data)

```
--LIVE GRADES JSON

SELECT
    STU.ID as [Student.PermID],
    CONCAT(STU.LN,', ',STU.FN) AS [Student.LastFirst],
    STU.GR as [Student.Grade],
    GBK.PD as [Student.Period],
    TCH.TE as [Student.TeacherName],
    TCH.TN as [Student.TeacherNum],
    GBU.CSC as [Student.Percentage],
    LEFT(GBU.CMK,1) as [Student.Mark],
    STU.U3 as [Student.User3],
    STU.LF as [Student.LangFlu],
    STU.CU as [Student.CounselorNum],
    CAST(GBU.DTS as date) as [Student.LastUpdate]

FROM GBK
JOIN TCH ON (TCH.SC = GBK.SC AND TCH.TN = GBK.TN AND TCH.DEL = 0)
JOIN GBU ON (GBU.SC = GBK.SC AND GBU.GN = GBK.GN AND GBU.DEL = 0)
JOIN STU ON (STU.SC = GBU.SC AND STU.SN = GBU.SN AND STU.DEL = 0)

WHERE 
    GBK.DEL = 0 AND
    GBK.SC = 994 AND 
    STU.GR IN (9, 10, 11, 12) AND 
    GBU.TG != 'I' AND
    (GBK.TM = 'Spring' OR GBK.TM = '3' OR GBK.TM = '4' OR GBK.TM = 'Year') and
    GBK.PD < 8

ORDER BY STU.LN, STU.ID, GBK.PD

FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Students')
```

I need help creating a URL and direction on where to "store" it so that it I can fetch the data at any point from a custom script within Google sheets rather than having to run the query in SSMS and copy+paste it into my spreadsheet. I have the JSON and I know how to parse it to a spreadsheet. I just do not know how I go about creating and storing a URL that I can fetch the data when I want it and it is always live connected back to my SQL Server Database.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken you need to build an API website which does all that you require. However thats a big job and unfortunately unsuitable as a question on this site.

Comment: You may be interested in publishing an web service on a web server that has access to your SQL Server. I wouldn't recommend putting your SQL server directly on the Internet. https://www.udemy.com/course/rest-api-flask-and-python/

Comment: As others have you will probably want to create an API to allow external access to your DB. This seems like a fairly easy way to convert your existing query into an API endpoint  https://github.com/formio/resquel